# Conversion to Time 12 hour Format From String containing Time in 24 hour format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a `varchar(5)` column in a table which contains the hour and minutes in 24 hour format time. I want to convert this 24 hour format to 12 hour format and finally embed this 12 hour format time into a DateTime Variable along with a Date value. Below is an example of demonstration.

For Example

> 8:18 should be converted into 8:18:00 AM and then should be embedded
>   with a Date like 8/10/2012 8:18:50 AM to be able to store in DateTime
>   column of DB.

```
22:20......10:20:00 PM.......8/10/2012 10:20:00 PM
```

The Date will not be current date it can be any date value like 8/8/2012 or 7/8/2012

Comment: I will retrieve that time value from user input, convert it into 12 hour format mentioned above, embed it with a date value saved in a label and insert it into DB

Comment: A `DateTime` value has no associated representation. So why do you want to convert to 12h format, when you convert to `DateTime` shortly afterwards?

Comment: what i want to do is that i have a date in string like string dt = "8/14/2012" and i have a time value in a string in 24hour format like "8:18".... Now what i want is that these both values should be combined to make a datetime value like final datetime  would be 
(8/14/2012 8:18:00 AM)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
string input = "22:45";

var timeFromInput = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "H:m", null, DateTimeStyles.None);

string timeIn12HourFormatForDisplay = timeFromInput.ToString(
    "hh:mm:ss tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var timeInTodayDate = DateTime.Today.Add(timeFromInput.TimeOfDay);
```

And now the important parts to take in consideration:

- The format for parsing uses `"H:m"` so it assumes a 24H value that does not use a zero to prefix single digits hours or minutes;
- The format for printing uses `"hh:mm:ss tt"` because it seems to be the format you desire, however you need to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to be certain that you get a AM/PM designator that is in fact AM or PM. If you use another culture, the AM/PM designator may change;
- The full date and time is constructed based on `DateTime.Today` which returns the today date with a zeroed time and then we just add the time we read from input.

To create the final date and time from another date you can instead use:

```
var timeInAnotherDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Add(timeFromInput.TimeOfDay);
```

---

Reference material:

- [DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx);
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx);
- [Standard DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Hey @João Angelo the creation of final date time

var timeInAnotherDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Add(timeFromInput.TimeOfDay);

you passed manually the date for the creation of datetime. What if i want to do that this date should always be input from a string. rather than as a manually entered argument. Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the format of the date, for example `"M/d/yyyy"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
create function dbo.COMBINE_DATE_TIME(
  @DatePart DateTime,                 -- DateTime
  @TimePart varchar(5))               -- Time
  returns DateTime
as begin
  return DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,@DatePart), 
    CONVERT(DateTime,ISNULL(@TimePart,''),14))
end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strDate = DateTime.ParseExact("8:18","HHmm",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: I think format is "HH:mm", but it wouldn't work at this case, cause string must be "08:18"

Answer (score 0):

```
            string fromTime = Convert.ToStr(reader["TimeFrom"]);
            string toTime = Convert.ToStr(reader["TimeTo"]);
            item.Time=DateTime.Parse(fromTime,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

here the property of your model(item.Time here) should be the string.